# How do I rename a filename after uploading with php?

Tags: php, file, rename

How do I rename the file either before or after it gets uploaded? I just want to rename the filename, not the extension.

```
$changeTXT = $_SESSION['username'];
$uploaderName = strtolower($changeTXT);
$changeTXT = strtolower($changeTXT);
$changeTXT = ucfirst($changeTXT);
$filelocation = $_POST['userfile'];
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
$max_size = $_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE'];

$file = $_FILES['userfile'];

$allowedExtensions = array("wma", "mp3", "wav");

function isAllowedExtension($fileName) {
  global $allowedExtensions;

  return in_array(end(explode(".", $fileName)), $allowedExtensions);
}

if($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
  if(isAllowedExtension($file['name'])) {

$uploaddir = "uploads/".$uploaderName."/";

$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

    echo "Thank you for uploading your music!<br /><br />";

} else {

    echo "Your file did not upload.<br /><br />";

}

    echo "\n";

    echo "<a href='index.php'>Return</a> to index.<br /><br />$uploaddir";

} else {

    echo "You have tried to upload an invalid file type.<br /><br />";

  }

} else die("Cannot upload");
```

Answer (score 22):

When using `move_uploaded_file` you get to pick the filename, so you can pick anything you want.

When you upload the file, its put into a temporary directory with a temporary name, `move_uploaded_file()` allows you to move that file and in that you need to set the name of the file as well.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest you to check out Verot's File Upload class. It heals a lot of the pain of file uploading via php, and makes your code much more readable / maintainable.

Here is the [link to the class](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm) and documentation.

As to the precise answer to  your question:
To give a new name to an uploaded file, put it as second argument to your move_uploaded_file() function.

Since you want to keep the extension, store it first in a variable:

```
$ext = explode('.',$_FILES['uploaded']['name']);
$extension = $ext[1];
```

You could use the file root name to generate the new name (here, with a timestamp appended to it):

```
$newname = $ext[0].'_'.time();
```

Say you uploaded a file, and your form input variable name is "myfile.png" it will become 'myfile_2343544.png';

Now, combine the local path to the target directory, the $newname var and the file's extension to set the function's second argument:

```
$full_local_path = 'path/to/your/filefolder/'.$newname.'.'.$extension ;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $full_local_path);
```

Comment: Alllllmost. But you need $newname.".$extension", adding a period between newname and extension, otherwise it comes out "filenamejpg". Upvoted!

Comment: I lost myself in the space between the dots... Nice catch, thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just save it with a different name:

Just change the name of the $uploadfile variable:

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . "somefilename" . end(explode(".", $file['name']));
```

It wouldn't hurt however if you refactord your code a little.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
```

Just set $uploadfile to the whole path of the desired filename; i.e. "uploads/mynewfilename.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the second param in move_uploaded_file to set the filename. The first param is the filename of the file in your /tmp folder and the second param is the file dir and the new filename.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "/new/file/dir/".[the new file name]);
```

I know this is an old question but there wasn't a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

  /*
     Just change the $path variable to your uploads path
     and dont forget the  / at the end of the  path.

     The way this function works is .When the user submits the form
     the uniqueFilename() function checks to see if there is a filename
     in your uploads folder, that has the same name as the one you intend
     to upload. If it finds a filename that has the same name as the one you want to
     upload it goes through the next steps


        Step 1

    strrpos($arg1,$arg2) - we use it to find the location where upload path ends and where the filename begins

    $arg1 = the filepath including the filename ex. uploads/myFile.jpg
    $arg2 = basename($filename); what this does is it  strips the path from the string and returns only the filename.

    When we use strrpos($arg1,$arg2) we basically tell the function to find the position of the path and exclude the filename

    Step 2

    substr($arg1,$arg2,$arg3) - looks in a string and extrats only the parts from the string that you want. We use it now to extract the uploads path.

    $arg1 = the full path of the uploaded file. ex. uploads/myFile.jpg
    $arg2 = 0  because we want to start from the begginning of the string
    $arg3 = $pathlocation which is the location of where the uploadpath ends and the file beggins

    when we use substr() here we intend to extract the uploads path.

    Step 3

    basename($arg1) strips out a path and returns the filename

    - we use this to save the original filename

    Notice that so far we have the path to the files saved and also
    the filename with its extension. We also have the file extension (.jpg|.png) or whatever


    Step 4

    pathinfo() - extracts the extension from the filename

    Step 5

    we us strrpos() to find the location of the last dot ( . ) in the filename because in step 6
    we use this location to cut the string where the dot ( . ) is

    Step 6

    substr() gets the file without the extension

    Step 7
    substr() takes the filename without extension and clips out the last charcter
    so if the filename is myFile this function would return myFil

    Step 8
    substr() again we use it to save the last character of the file so
                if our file is called myFile it would return e.

    Step 9
    Here we check to see if the last character of our file is numeric.
    Why do this? Because if the last character of a file is numeric we can just add a number to the
    file and end up with a new file with an added number so our file is
    myFile1 the 1 is numeric so our intention is to add to it
    so my myFile1 would end up being myFile2. But what happens if our last character is not numeric?

    then we just add -1 to the file so that myFile would end up being myFile-1

    Step 10
    Since our filename exists in the database we must call the function uniqueFilename() again so that we can
    check and see if the new name exists in the database.

    This function basically keeps calling itself until it finds a filename that does not exists.
   */





    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $path = "uploads/";

    $fullPath = $path.$_FILES['uploadFile']['name'];
    $full_local_path = $path.uniqueFilename($fullPath) ;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], $full_local_path);
    }
          /*
             * Function returns a unique filename
             * Param 1 is the path of the filename and the filename
             * returns filename with no path
             */
            function uniqueFilename($filepathAndFilename){

                // check to see if file exists
                if (file_exists($filepathAndFilename))
                {
                        /* step 1 */

                    //Get the path location without the basename
                  $filePathWithoutFilenameLocationInString = strrpos($filepathAndFilename,basename($filepathAndFilename));

                        /* step 2 */

                    //Get the path and cut the basename
                    $path = substr($filepathAndFilename,0,$filePathWithoutFilenameLocationInString);

                        /* Step 3*/
                    //Get the base filename
                    $filename = basename($filepathAndFilename);

                       /* Step 4 */
                       // get the extension
                    $fileExtension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                        /* Step 5 */
                    // find the position of the last dot
                    $dotLocation = strrpos($filename,'.');

                        /* Step 6 */
                    // Get the filename without the dot
                    $fileWithNoExtension = substr($filename,0,$dotLocation);

                        /* Step 7 */
                    //Get the name without the last character
                    $filenameMinusLastCharacter = substr($fileWithNoExtension,0,-1);

                       /* Step 8 */
                    //save the last character
                    $lastFilenameCharacter = substr($fileWithNoExtension,-1);

                        /* Step 9*/
                    //if the last character is numeric add 1
                    if (is_numeric($lastFilenameCharacter))
                    {
                        $newFilename = $path.$filenameMinusLastCharacter.($lastFilenameCharacter+1).'.'.$fileExtension;
                        //recursively call itself

                         /* Step 10*/
                        $results = uniqueFilename($newFilename);
                        return basename($results);
                    }else{

                        // if the last character is not numeric then add 1
                        $newFilename = $path.$fileWithNoExtension.'-1'.'.'.$fileExtension;

                            /* Step 10*/
                        //recursively call itself
                        $results = uniqueFilename($newFilename);
                        return basename($results);
                    }

                }
                return basename($filepathAndFilename);

            }
    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
    <label>Upload File</label>
    <input type="file" name="uploadFile"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>`enter code here`
```

Comment: It is always helpful if you also explain the answer. It will make your answer even better, and more likely to get upvoted.