# Changing a Filename on Upload

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how to rename the photo that is being uploaded to my server via the code below. I am able to properly upload the photo, but I can't figure out how to change the name.

For example, how would I rename the photo so that it would be called "renamed_image"?

Thank you!

```
<?php
    $target_path = "./user_photos/";  

    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']);  

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {  
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['picture']['name'])." has been uploaded";  
    } else{  
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";  
    } 
 ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I rename a filename after uploading with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701230/how-do-i-rename-a-filename-after-uploading-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename  = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$new       = md5($filename).'.'.$extension;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "/path/{$new}")) 
{
   // other code
}
```

Hope this helps

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file extention
$file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file name
$filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
$allowed_file_types = array('.doc','.docx','.rtf','.pdf');  

if (in_array($file_ext,$allowed_file_types) && ($filesize < 200000))
{   
    // Rename file
    $newfilename = md5($file_basename) . $file_ext;
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $newfilename))
    {
        // file already exists error
        echo "You have already uploaded this file.";
    }
    else
    {       
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $newfilename);
        echo "File uploaded successfully.";     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
$target_path = $target_path . $username . $extension; 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code something like this

$updated_name = str_replace(' ','-',str_basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']);
$updated_name = rand(10,200).$updated_name;

Here we use str_replace as in filename there can be some extra space which when upload throws an error so str_replace will remove that and adding a random number to the file name will solve another problem ie . If user upload same filename twice then both filename will be different now as random digit is added